# Layer control and geojson loading

Tags: javascript, leaflet

How do make one geojson layer the default layer?
I have multiple geojson for different point data.  I am using leaflet layer control with radio buttons (so only one dataset is displayed at a time).  I am also using the markercluster support plugin, which works great.  The problem is when the map loads all of the geojson data is available at the same time until I start switching layers on the control.  I am using Objoverlays and baseoverlay in my L.control

Answer (score 0):

Add only the default layer to the map before you add the layer control. Don't add the other layers.

Comment: The solution is to use the checkIn method: layersupportgroup.checkIn(layer1); layersupportGroup.addTo(map)